# Difficulty processing data received over serial port

Tags: serial-port, c++-cli

I am a somewhat newby VC++ writer, most of my work has been in C on embedded systems.  I need to write a test and calibration program for an embedded system I am designing, and I have a problem.  The code I am starting with (found at http://abhishek4273.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/serial-port-and-visual-studio/ ) basically puts all the received data in a text box.  I need to use that received data, and respond appropriately  The basic serial handling routine i have now is:

```
    private: System::Void SetTextCallback(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
    this->txtTransfer->AppendText(data1);
    data3 = data3 + data1;
    Data = this->txtTransfer->Text;
    }

private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived_1(System::Object^ sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^ e) 
     {
    data1 = serialPort1->ReadExisting();
    this->Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::SetTextCallback));
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to just copy the received data into a new buffer called data3. (All data is handled as Strings) and tried to process that.  My problem is that data3 often has incomplete or extra data.  What I need is a way to make sure I have received an entire line of data to process, terminated by a return.

My data processing routine is:

```
    private: System::Void btnMemTest_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         // button to test flash memory receive functions
         // create array to hold memory
         unsigned char memtest[4096];
         unsigned int i, j;

         // Send 'n' on serial port, followed by memory start address
         this->serialPort1->Write("n");
         while (String::Compare(data3, "n?"));
         data3 = "";
         this->serialPort1->Write("000000");

         for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
         {
             while (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(data1))
             j = Convert::ToInt16(data3,16);
             memtest[i] = j;
             data3 = "";
             this->serialPort1->Write("y");
         }
         this->serialPort1->Write("n");
}
```

Right now, it hangs at 
    while (String::Compare(data3, "n?"));
because only "n" is in the data3.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Update to question: Is the serial receive process interrupt driven?  Or, does it stop when I go into my data handling process?  I have noticed that the data in my strings are not consistent with each other, almost as though the serial receive routines are not running while in this process...

Comment: That's C++/CLI not C++. Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Just use ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting().

Comment: Any reason you can't use C#/.NET considering you're already using C++/CLI and need the CLR?

Comment: Updated to C++/CLI.  Does ReadLine() only trigger is there is a CR or NL?  I have had a class in C++, never worked in C# before!

Comment: The [Windows serial port functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) work great, the .NET wrappers are horrible.

Comment: If you're unwilling to use the C/C++ API in C++, then at least use the .NET wrapper in a less horrible way.  http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a buffer of data that wasn't a complete message.  Whenever new data comes in, stick it on the end of the buffer.  Then check for and remove complete messages.  There might be extra sticking around in the buffer for the next block received.

With respect to your update: serial ports are buffered.  As long as you aren't actually closing the serial port, you won't lose data just because your program was busy when it arrived (at least, not without having a buffer overfull error).

Comment: I was trying to do this, by creating String data3, but it isn't working.  Have tried :
data3 = data3 + data1;
data3 = String::Concat(data3, data1);

and neither of them seem to be working.  Result is empty string.  What could be so wrong with something so basic????

Comment: @CharlesEdmondson: Use `byte[]` (or `List<byte>`), not `string`, to hold serial data.  List's `AddRange` and `RemoveRange` functions are good in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, Ben, but the form seems to be all set up to deal with String data.  Going to byte[] will mean a lot of casting about...

Comment: @Charles: You can decode as a string after you concatenate partial reads and find your message separators.  You also definitely want to use `byte[]` if there's any CRC calculation going on.

Comment: Don't really need to do that much with it.  Interesting data: if I put data1 in front, it works, but with data3 in front, it doesn't.  If data3 is empty, can it not add data to it?????

Comment: @CharlesEdmondson: You also have some serious threading problems.  While your click handler is running, the call to `SetTextCallback` is just sitting in a queue... the variable `data3` will never be changed.  Polling like `while (String::Compare(data3, "n?"));` will not work, your whole program deadlocks.